# How to customize a reusable Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm using "SubCategoryTiles" widget all over the app. initially i was using same Group Icon but now i want to use different-different **category_Icon** wherever i use this widget. So i want to know how to do it. See the code and also the image with error i'm getting.

```
class SubCategoryTiles extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubCategoryTiles({
    required this.titleText,
    required this.onTapHandler,
    required this.category_Icon,
  });

  final Widget titleText;
  final VoidCallback onTapHandler;
  final IconData category_Icon;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: const CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: category_Icon,
        
        // Icon(
        //   Icons.group,
        //   color: Colors.deepOrange,
        // ),
      ),
      title: titleText,
      trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
      onTap: onTapHandler,
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your category_Icon in a Icon widget

```
child: Icon(category_Icon),
```

IconData is not a widget, but an Icon is.

Comment: after adding your answer, it shows this error "Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions. Try making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor."

Comment: Remove the const before CircleAvatar

Answer (score 0):

The should be like this:

```
class SubCategoryTiles extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubCategoryTiles({
    required this.titleText,
    required this.onTapHandler,
    required this.category_Icon,
  });

  final Widget titleText;
  final VoidCallback onTapHandler;
  final IconData category_Icon;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: Icon(
          category_Icon,
          color: Colors.deepOrange,
        ),

        // Icon(
        //   Icons.group,
        //   color: Colors.deepOrange,
        // ),
      ),
      title: titleText,
      trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
      onTap: onTapHandler,
    );
  }
}
```

// This is how it should be added when you require it.

category_Icon: Icons.add_box,